# jacoco.exec file is empty

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to generate a report on code coverage for my functional test cases of one module(java project). I am trying to do it from command line. Basically I run a shell script to run my application and I am adding the below arguments in the shell script so that I can create jacoco.exec file, which could be later converted to HTML report.

**-javaagent:/root/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/root/jacoco/data/jacoco.exec**

Why is jacoco.exec file being created empty?

Answer (score 2):

jacoco.exec is always creatd empty. It is filled on JVM exit.

Jacoco use shutdown hook to launch a dump of data in jacoco.exec.

Alternatively you can trigger a dump by exeucting the following :

> Can I collect coverage information without stopping the JVM?
>   Yes, there are two possible ways: The JaCoCo agent can be configured for remote control via TCP/IP sockets. This allows to collect execution data at any point in time from a running JVM. The dump Ant task or the dump Maven goal can be used to request dumps. The remote control feature also allows you to reset 
>    execution data.
>
> Alternatively the JaCoCo agent can be configured to expose some functionality via JMX (jmx=true). The bean org.jacoco:type=Runtime provides operations to 
>    dump and reset execution data at any point in time

see more here : http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html